# How to use the cmd+w shortcut without closing a Fluid app?

Tags: macos, ide, fluid.app

I am using Coder.com, an online IDE, as a Fluid app.

I want cmd+w and cmd-t to close and open new tabs inside the IDE, not the Fluid app. Is there any way I can overwrite these shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

Quit your Fluid.app, and then follow these steps:

1. Go to System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » App Shortcuts.
2. Click the "+"
3. In the pop-up window, change "Application" from "All Applications" to "Your Fluid App.app"
4. Set the Menu Title to "Close Tab"
5. Set the Keyboard Shortcut to something else like `⌘⌥W`
6. Click "Add"

Then repeat steps 2-6 for "New Tab", like so:

7. Click the "+"
8. In the pop-up window, change "Application" from "All Applications" to "Your Fluid App.app"
9. Set the Menu Title to "New Tab"
10. Set the Keyboard Shortcut to something else, like `⌘⌥T`
11. Click "Add"

Go to Coder.com and use their keyboard settings to set Close Tab and New Tab to `⌘W` and `⌘T`